# Django makemigration error in only a table

Tags: django-models

I have a django 1.8 project and I use so many models. I decide to create a new column in an specific model but it doesn't work because "the column 'x' doesn't exists". When I try the same in other model it works fine, is just in that model. I could drop that model and create it again, but I need to fix it without erase anything. Any idea?

`column = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)`

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
... django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column table.column doesn't exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could update my model by editing the migration.py file like:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('appName', '000X_auto_...'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='modelName',
        name='column',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True),
    ),
```